# Mongodb colelction find in cron job throws new Error('Can\'t wait without a fiber');

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, cron, fiber

I have set up a cron job using the npm package [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron). I am trying to do the following `Coll.find().forEach` function but I am getting the error `Error: Can't wait without a fiber`

```
    var job = new CronJob({
      cronTime: '00 09 11 * * 1-5',
      onTick: function() {
            var userIds = []

            Coll.find().forEach(function(doc) {
                    userIds.push(doc._id)
            });
      },
      start: false,
      timeZone: "Europe/London"
    });
   job.start();
```

I have been using npm packages fibers and future library. I still got the same error.

```
var resultOne = collFind();


  function collFind() {
     var f = new future()
     var userIds = []

     Coll.find().forEach(function(doc) {
        userIds.push(doc.userId)
    });

    return f['return']({userIds:userIds}
    return f.wait()
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`Meteor.bindEnvironment`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/556c0e28e94b9351cbf0b28e80a71a4e35f1362a/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js#L84).

```
var job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '00 09 11 * * 1-5',
  onTick: Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
        var userIds = []

        Coll.find().forEach(function(doc) {
                userIds.push(doc._id)
        });
  }),
  start: false,
  timeZone: "Europe/London"
});
job.start();
```

It will ensure that the callback get's run in the current fiber, and ensure all global variables are accessible.

Comment: Nathan, this was perfect. Now I know what bindEnvironment does.